# PHP send mail to multiple email

Tags: php, email

I have a code

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['invite'])) {
  foreach($_POST['invite'] as $check) {
   }
$import_emails =  implode($_POST['invite'], ',');
$imp_eml = explode(',', $import_emails);

$mail->AddAddress($imp_eml [0]);
$mail->AddBCC($imp_eml);
......
......
}     
?>
```

I want to send multiple emails in AddBCC but i am confuse how to send and which type loop i should use for send multiple emails.

have any idea?

Comment: put this: $mail->AddAddress($email); inside a foreach( $imp_eml as $email) { /* code here */ } loop

Answer (score 1):

You usually can send to multiple recipients by separating them with a ;

edit: woops, forget about it :D

Answer (score 1):

AddAddress should be in loop:

```
foreach ($imp_eml as $addr){
    $mail->AddAddress($addr);
    $mail->AddBCC($addr);
}
```

Comment: M sorry ....@Adam i want to accept but my reputation is only 6 so its not possible...

Comment: @ShubhamVema - I've just give You 10 :) I Hope that You can accept answer now :)

Comment: Thanks ....@Adam, can you help again me?
The link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241668/hide-others-recipients-when-sending-multiple-mails?noredirect=1#comment28481449_19241668

Comment: @ShubhamVema - use FDL comment :)

Comment: Hello ...@Adam, Please help me again, click on this link and give a precious solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241668/hide-others-recipients-when-sending-multiple-mails