# hide others recipients when sending multiple mails

Tags: php, email

I have some code like this, after sending mail in AddAddress and AddBCC showing all recipients, I want to hide all others recipients, how can i hide it have you any idea?

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['invite'])) {
foreach($_POST['invite'] as $check) {
    }
$import_emails =  implode($_POST['invite'], ',');
$imp_eml = explode(',', $import_emails);

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
foreach ($imp_eml as $addr)
  {
$mail->AddAddress($addr);
$mail->AddBCC($addr);
 }  

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->From = 'info@myweb.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Someone';
$mail->Host = '********';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = '*******';
$mail->Password = '*******';

if($mail->Send())
{
echo "success";
} else {
echo "failure";
}
?>
```

Comment: Send the e-mails separately or send to all recipients as BCC.

Comment: I don't know PHPMailer, but apparently you're adding every recipient twice: `$mail->AddAddress($addr); $mail->AddBCC($addr);` So they're in BCC (what is correct) and in To (what is wrong). Only add them to BCC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I recall, you can add BCC recipients using :

```
$mail->AddBCC('recipient@domain.com', 'Person');
```

BCC (Blind Carbon Copy) recipients are not writen to the mail headers, and therefore, are not shown to anyone receiving the e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

There is 3 possibilities as to add a person as a recipient in a mail.
In the TO:, in the CC: and in the BCC:

BCC stands for Blind Carbon Copy, and means that all the people that are on BCC will receive a copy of the mail but won't be able to see their respective addresses.

That is what you want I guess.